# Eclipse problems view not showing warnings

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a very similar problem to these threads: [Eclipse Problems View not showing Errors anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253357/eclipse-problems-view-not-showing-errors-anymore) and [Eclipse Problems View doesn't show Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503082/eclipse-problems-view-doesnt-show-errors)

However, my problem is that warnings are not showing up any longer, instead of errors.  Errors show up just fine.  They aren't showing up in files either.  I tried the solutions in that thread anyways, but no luck.

I even tried going to Configure Contents and added a configuration to show everything with severity of "Warning".  I tried moving the project to another computer, and warnings showed up just fine.  I tried re-installing Eclipse, and the same issue appeared.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a problem with the Java compiler settings where you describe whether each kind compile issue (e.g. local value not read, etc.) is to be treated as an error, warning or simple ignored.

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings and confirm that the warnings you expect to be flagged are in fact configured to be warnings.

Comment: That was it.  Somehow those settings got changed, and I'm not sure how, considering I wasn't aware they existed until now.  Thanks!