# Why "Access restriction" errors do not appear on Eclipse's Problems view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

One of the plugins from my Eclipse RCP project has lots of Access restriction errors on its classes, but those errors are not being listed on Eclipse's Problems view.

Even worse, the classes are not being decorated with the red marker on Package Explorer.

I'm being forced to open each and every file to discover which of them have errors.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I'm using Eclipse Photon.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503082/eclipse-problems-view-doesnt-show-errors) is about the same problem, but none of its answers worked for me.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of this happening, and the `.classpath` and `.project` files?

Answer (score 2):

Odds are you are either Filtering them out or have exceeded the set Limit for how many the View will show. Both of these are reconfigurable.

http://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cprbview.htm?cp=0_2_4_5

Comment: Nope.  The view is not being filtered neither exceeding any limits.